# RestController design struggle - Spring Boot REST API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I'm quite new into REST API development. I have decided to create a Blog application using Spring Boot and I'm really struggling with the design and structure of my app.

Right now my app consists of Post and Comment models and repositories. For both models, I have created service classes (PostService and CommentService). In these classes, I have all the business logic (just simple CRUD right now).

Now I am scratching my head about the design of my @RestControler for Posts. In PostController I have exposed these actions:

```java
@PostMapping("/api/posts/create")
public Post create(@RequestBody Post post) { ... }

@GetMapping("/api/posts")
public List<Post> findAll() { ... }

@GetMapping("/api/posts/{id}")
public Post findById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) { ... }

@PutMapping("/api/posts/{id}")
public Post update(@RequestBody Post post) { ... }

@DeleteMapping("/api/posts/{id}")
public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) { ... }
```

Now I'm getting to my question. I am wondering what is correct design of adding a Comment to the Post.

1. Should I expose all CRUD method for Comment using CommentController class and use create method?
2. Is it ok to add a new method `addComment` to PostController which will create a new Comment?

In my head adding a Comment to the Post belongs to the Post, but I really don't know.

Could some of give me some advice regarding this matter?

Thanks a lot!

Bye,
Tom

Comment: Your api doesn't look to bad! You can remove create from /api/posts/create because the POST Request still implies that you create a Post. For adding a Comment you can add a CommentController which has a dependency to your two services (PostService and CommentService). The URL could look like this /api/posts/{id}/comment . Have a look at this https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

Comment: Create a new Controller to handle the comment functionalities. Keeping them in the same controller will make that controller cumbersome as you will have to add other functionalities to the comment section at some point.

Comment: Thank you guys.... just one question. Since it does not make sense to have comments without post, is it correct to use URL like this in CommentController: @PostMapping("/api/post/{id}/commets") for create method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd consider REST Design Principles from the [OpenAPI Specification](http://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3) and would follow `resource -> sub-resource -> method||identifier` pattern. This would probably be the most KISS and clean design for the readability and understanding purposes.

```
@PostMapping("/api/posts/") //you don't need /create as a separate URI
public Post create(@RequestBody Post post) { ... }

@GetMapping("/api/posts") //This is OK.
public List<Post> findAll() { ... }

@GetMapping("/api/posts/{id}") //OK, however {id} should be optional, hence you can combine this and upper methods in one method.
public Post findById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) { ... }

@PutMapping("/api/posts/{id}") //OK.
public Post update(@RequestBody Post post) { ... }

@DeleteMapping("/api/posts/{id}") //OK.
public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) { ... }
```

and now, for the comments API design, I would have contain them under *posts* resource, and would have added these corresponding URIs:

```
@GetMapping("/api/posts/{id}/comments/{commendId}") //commentId is optional
@PostMapping("/api/posts/{id}/comments/") //you don't need any {commendId} here, just post the payload
```

and etc. I hope you can come up with method signatures and other method mappings.

You can also see the RESTful naming conventions [here](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer. Could just explain to me why would you keep Comment methods inside the PostController?

Comment: @TomášNa'viKoválik not methods, per se, but resource path URIs under the posts URIs. Think from the Representation Perspective. Comment doesn't exist on its own without its parent resource `Post`, right? so handling comments separately wouldn't be the intuitive and understandable design when you expose your API to the 3rd party world. Besides, if you'll create two discrete URIs, (as accepted answer suggest) for GET and POST, this will violate DRY principle as well.. and you'll just have duplication, which is not good.

Comment: OK, now it makes more sense to me. One more question: if I decide in the future to use comments not only for Posts, then I should expose separate API for Comments, right?

Comment: First you should hold on before coding and think well your design. :) What your comments will be? what for? where you would use them?.. you first have to come up with the abstract design of *What you are trying to achieve* and then.. it depends on what you consider your comments will be. In your current example, it's crystal clear, that you have a *posts*, and you have their respective *comments*. So, as PID doesn't exist without person, similarly, comment won't exist if you don't have its parent post (if you, for example, delete the post).

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I don't think that someone can give you the perfect answer here. It is often a personal decision. In common you can say the following about a REST API.

- the path should only represent your data structure in the database. So for example `/api/posts`
- No verbs in your path. **What** you want to do should be handled by the RequestType (GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, etc.)

Now to your case. I can really good understand why you are struggling. I think here are two options:

1. **PostsController**

   You say a `Comment` is always a part of a `Post` and because of this
   you design your API like this.

   ```
   @PostMapping("/api/posts/{id}/comment")
   public Comment create(@PathVariable Long id), @RequestBody Comment comment) { ... }
   ```
2. **CommentsController**

   You handle `Comment` as an own object and the `Post` is just a relation you add to it by attribute.

   ```
   @PostMapping("/api/comments")
   public Comment create(@RequestBody Comment comment) { ... }
   ```

So it is always **is it a Subset** vs **make own Object structure**. I think in this case here I would prefer option 2 because I think you want do more operations on this object.

Also you can than design your API in the way that every Controller starts with the object that will be handled `/api/OBJECT/xxx/yyy`

**UPDATE**

After reading the comment from @gulliva I think also a good way is to use this URL `@PostMapping("/api/posts/{id}/comment")` but put it in the **CommentsController**. I think this is a good way.